# kernprof command not found - Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, line-profiler

I just installed line_profiler using pip on Ubuntu.  I closed and reopened the terminal, cd'd into the directory with my file to time, and ran kernprof.  Bash is telling me it can't find kernprof.
Coincidentally, I just did the exact same procedure on windows and it worked fine.

EDIT:  So pip didn't actually install it, or put kernprof in the wrong directory.  Downloading the tarball from pypi and running setup works.

Comment: Are you certain the installation was successful? As I understand it, the executable created by pip should be `/usr/bin/kernprof`. Does this file exist? Is it set executable? Does your user have permission to access it?

Comment: @0range, that is what was wrong.  Pip claimed it was installed but it wasn;t.  I downloaded it from pypi and ran setup.  Now it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have used instructions from the github [https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profilerhttps://) to install it, then you have probably used command: `pip install . --user`. The command installs a package into `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` (or whatever is you default python `python --version`), and the corresponding executable is in `~/.local/bin/`.

Based on this, you can run `kernprof` with:

```
~/.local/bin/kernprof -l -v my_script.py
```

or you can create a symlink with:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/kernprof /usr/local/bin/kernprof
```

and then run it with:

```
kernprof -l -v my_script.py
```